Usage of two PSU in parallel for WiFi router using Schottky diodes
I have Wi-Fi router which is powered by AC adapter with nominal output 9 V, 0.6 A. Due to power outages I have bought USB DC-DC adapter 5 V ⇾ 9 V and power it from power bank/power station. Router power consumption is around 1-2 W.
I have made connector that combine both power supplies together in parallel as shown in picture. With this connector both PSU will be all time connected to router and work either together or one will work and another will be unpowered but still connected.
I do not know how those supply will work together, especially if one PSU is unpowered. Maybe they have some internal protection against reverse (or should I call it back voltage, I don't know) voltage.
So I decided to protect them using diode. I have selected 1N5817 Schottky diode rated for 20 V, 1 A.
After I made connector and plug it, everything seems fine. I have right polarity and router working fine.
Only one moment — when I plug one PSU into my connector and measure voltage at other connector inlet, I observe voltage 4.5-6 V (4.5 V at one plug and 6 V at another if I switch PSU connector). Is it OK? I assume diode don't block current completely (datasheet tell that diode allows 1 mA back current) therefore some voltage will be present.
And what is your general verdict about my scheme, does it make sense? I assume this is a little bit of overengineering and even without diodes PSU will somehow handle each other.




It is very unclear what you are actually seeing from how you describe it.  You have 2 voltages 4.5V and 6V.  Where specifically?  At the same time?  What is output to router?  Define a moment?  What I am politely asking for is you to take that paragraph and expand it.  Because it is hard to get 9V out from either 4.5V or 6V.  And the way diodes work, is only one will drive load.

Thanks for reply. Here I showed voltages on scheme. https://i.imgur.com/MjzB5hW.png

If I plug PSU into other connector I got 4.5 V. https://i.imgur.com/diTVHdX.png

Define a moment?  And when you measure 6V, is the USB cord plugged in?

I think OP is trying to test the Diode-OR circuit that is intended to isolate the two supplies from each other. He removes one supply completely and replaces it with a very high-impedance voltmeter.  When the remaining supply is switched on, the meter shows a small transient voltage behind the diode (where the other removed supply would normally be).  @1n5817 Does the measured voltage decay back toward zero when this occurs?  I may just be parasitic capacitance across the diode, so no significant power to damage anything when supply actually connected.

@1n5817 to test my parasitic capacitance theory and make your test more realistic, try keeping both supplies connected. Start with both supplies powered off and place the voltmeter again between anode of diode and circuit ground (which we assume is connecting everything, but not shown in your diagram).  Now turn on the supply on the side that is not being measured.  Same as your original test and observe the voltage (but now the powered off supply will have parasitic capacitance/impedance to ground too that easily will absorb tiny energy).

Yes. BK303 is right. I want to isolate two supplies from each other. I unplug ine power supply and replace it with multimeter.
As for voltage decaying - no, voltage is constant.

I have also tested my connector in another way. I have plugged one input with 12 V chemical battery I have (so I assume no transient effects should appear). Than I have measured voltage at another input (where voltage should be zero in theory, if diode work as ideal diode) and I measured 6.5 V. At output I have 12 V as expected. Here I made scheme with negative wire shown (I assume I shown it right). Sorry for cluttered explanation. https://imgur.com/a/TIE2rN8

DOnt know is it help but I made another test. I have connected 15 Ohm resistor to second plug as shown in scheme and measured current. Current through resistor R1 is around 20 microAmperes. So diode block current as advertised in datsheet. https://i.imgur.com/EQyFVth.png

What you measure is perfectly normal.
While Schottky diodes have less forward voltage drop than a standard diode, they leak current in reverse much more than a standard diode, which is what you observe with the multimeter.
And since you are measuring the floating input with a very high impedance multimeter, it won't be uncommon to see maybe 12V on both sides of the schottky diode.
As you saw, loading down the floating input brings the voltage down as the current is so tiny.
And no, this isn't over-engineered at all. You cannot assume that either of the supplies won't burn up in flames if you simply connected them together in parallel, both feeding each other. Especially bad when one supply turns off.

Thank you for answer.
